# restore database from .file format

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-restore

Currently, I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012, My client gives me only file format database file.When I select this file for restore, Error occurs

> "No backupset selected to be restored"

I was already trying to change file extension change to dot[.] bak format but it also not work.

So how can I restore database file from file format(not .bak format) to Microsoft SQL Server 2012?

Comment: So the file extension is ".file"? If the "file format" is not a database backup, it could be a SQL script, database file, or something else.

Comment: Try to open the file with a text editor to understand if it is a script or a backupset or something else